# Hacer un ejecutable de un archivo python en el cual hace el llamado de una clase de otro archivo QtDesigner

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, qt-designer

Acabo de terminar una interfaz en qt5 designer y pues le hice el llamado en otro archivo python. El programa funciona excelente.

Ahora quiero hacer un ejecutable de ello, pero al hacerlo con pyinstaller no sale correcto, ya que no funciona.

Debo aclarar que hice la conversión a ejecutable de solo el archivo python donde hago el llamado del archivo de Qtdesigner. También utilizo imágenes dentro del QtDesigner.

Intenté hacerlo con el pyintaller, pero al querer abrir el ejecutable no se ejecuta.

Comment: Si deseas ayuda debes proveer un [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un *program.py* y quieres crear un *program.exe* con *pyinstaller*:

```
pyinstaller program.py
```

Si quieres ocultar la consola de comandos:

```
pyinstaller --windowed program.py
```

Si además quieres que *program.exe* sea un *standalone*:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed program.py
```

Pero en este caso **tienes que añadir los recursos que utiliza *program.exe* al propio ejecutable**. Por ejemplo, si tienes un archivo *interfaz.ui*:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "interfaz.ui;." program.py
```

Ahora *interfaz.ui* es un recurso del ejecutable. Al ejecutar *program.exe* se descomprime *interfaz.ui* en el directorio `sys._MEIPASS` (si estás utilizando el *flag --onefile*), y como `os.getcwd() != sys._MEIPASS` **el programa no puede enconrtar el archivo *interfaz.ui*.**

**Para solucionarlo `sys._MEIPASS` tiene que ser el directorio de trabajo:**

```
import sys, os

if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)

# Si existe sys._MEIPASS significa que el programa
# se está ejecutando como un standalone program.exe,
# y si no existe es que está ejecutándose como
# python program.py
```

Ahora, si ejecutas:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "interfaz.ui;." program.py
```

El programa funcionará correctamente.